# In OpenGL, what is "zero state" rendering?

Tags: opengl, rendering, graphics-programming, terminology

Recently at a job interview, I mentioned that I taught myself modern OpenGL and rendering with vertex buffer objects because my university only taught the fixed function pipeline with immediate mode rendering at the time. The interviewer briefly interrupted me to say that VBOs have effectively been replaced by something called "zero state rendering" and then let me continue.

I forgot to ask later on about what that meant, because we quickly moved onto different subjects and the interviewer had run out of time at the end due to a busy schedule.

Later, I searched online for "OpenGL zero state" and "zero state rendering" with no results that seemed relevant, mostly just things about the OpenGL state.

The organization in question is very heavily research based, so is there a chance that it is an extension with currently little support, or that the terminology used varies due to it's cutting edge nature?

Comment: Are you certain it was "zero state", or could it have been something else with a word "zero" in it? My guess is that he was talking about zero overhead: http://gdcvault.com/play/1020791/

Comment: There's a good chance that it could be 'zero overheard', from skimming the video, although I am 100% certain his actual words were 'zero state'. My assumption was that he was referring to a single new feature used for draw calls, as opposed to optimizing what was already available. Is 'zero overhead' the new, recommended way of drawing things in OpenGL?

Comment: "zero overhead" OpenGL in no way replaces VBOs, though. Nothing has replaced VBOs, at least not in the common case. They're how you upload per-vertex data to a GPU. Nothing new there. There are a handful of techniques you can pull off without any vertex data; maybe she meant that? The term is not in common use, though. She may have just misspoke or misunderstood what you were talking about.

Comment: Zero overhead is not just a single thing, but a set of tricks that you can pull off to reduce the opengl driver overhead to almost zero. These tricks include for example putting everything in single VBO, using advanced instancing techniques, using megatextures or texture arrays, and so on. Just watch the video.

Comment: Could it have been "zero attribute"?  Zero-attribute rendering (often called "attributeless rendering") *does* replace VBOs.

Comment: @TrevorPowell A search led me to this: http://renderingpipeline.com/2012/03/attribute-less-rendering/ . It seems like it can only really be used for predefined geometric shapes, and even then only in the core profile so it doesn't seem to me that it's quite a replacement for VBOs if you want to load vertex data from disk.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about term explanation. Should we open a topic on every term out there? - that won't be such a good idea. Furthermore, the term seems to be "made up" - only the person who made it can explain it.

Comment: @usm Vertex data from disk is also "only predefined geometric shapes".  Not sure what your point is.

Comment: Fine, perhaps "predefined geometric shapes" was probably not the correct phrase but it's clear that my point was that loading meshes from a file is far more flexible than hardcoding vertex positions. If my understanding of the technique in the linked post is incorrect, an explanation would have been helpful, or at the very least not posting if you were just going to resort to dismissive pedantry.

Comment: @usm It wasn't dismissive pedantry.  Using attribute-less rendering you can load a mesh from a shader file instead of loading it from a model file.  If you're really dead set on only ever loading models from model files for some reason, then you can even generate the attribute-less shader source yourself in code, at runtime, based on the model file's data, without ever putting the model data into a VBO.  I'm not saying this is necessarily always the best way to do things, just that it's something that you can do and definitely not worthy of immediate scorn.

Comment: Ah I see. I forgot the possibility that shader files aren't set in stone at build time unlike the main program code. I now have a better idea what the interviewer meant and I'll be sure to ask for details if I ever hear from them again. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: This question is *not* off-topic, [terminology](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/terminology) questions are absolutely permitted.

Comment: I'm quite certain that what your interviewer was talking about was what is more commonly known as Bindless Rendering.  In short, it removes the need to bind individual objects to global handles in order to change or utilize them.  You should get better results searching for that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your interviewer was talking, with his own words, about *bindless* API. nVidia made nice presentations recently about all that, which they call *direct state access* ([1](http://www.geeks3d.com/20101228/opengl-direct-state-access-dsa/), [2](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/docs/OpenGL%204.x%20and%20Beyond.pdf))). This does not replace VBOs.

---

*EDIT*: Actually, let's consider Trevor Powell's suggestion:

This seems like some people could definitely decide to drop VBOs, in favor of attribute-less rendering, using geometry shaders fetching uniform data or textures, as mentioned in [this article](http://renderingpipeline.com/2012/03/are-vertex-shaders-obsolete/).

I can see how somebody could decide to switch one's engine to full attirubte-less, but I would not condone such a move if I was in the team:
The reason—if you read [this overview of the pipeline](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/03/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-part-3/) carefully—is that with attribute-less, the vertex FIFO cache becomes unusable as it's skipped altogether.
Attribute-less hence removes a nice optimization opportunity.

This needs benchmarking of course, but purely a-priori, it sounds like a bad idea for a generic, all purpose solution.